# How to parse markdown in react-native (esp. android)?

Tags: react-native

Since React Native webview components is only support iOS, I wonder what other options are available to parse markdown strings for android. Anyone had worked with markdown in React Native for Android app?

Answer (score 2):

See if this solves the problem: https://github.com/lwansbrough/react-native-markdown

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [**`react-native-markdown-view`**](https://github.com/Benjamin-Dobell/react-native-markdown-view) which we're using at 2minute.com.

It's the only RN Markdown lib I found that properly renders a list.  It's also the only one to have merged a pull request in the last month.

Alternatives: I've tried others in some depth but they can't do lists properly. `react-native-simple-markdown` renders the list bullet in the middle instead of at the top of the list item, and the styling was also bugged. `react-native-markdown-renderer` renders lists off the right side of the screen.  `react-native-markdown` hasn't been touched in 3 years so I skipped that one.